# How to remove inline style using jQuery

Tags: jquery

```
<table class="prtlPageConR" style="width: 100%;" cellSpacing="0" cellPadding="0">
```

Trying to remove style="width: 100%;" using:

```
$(".prtlPageConR table").css({"width":"0px");
```

But it doesn't work.

Ideas?

Comment: Missing `}` for the object literal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your selector is incorrect, you're looking for a `table` child of `.prtlPageConR`, *not* a `table` element with a `class` of `.prtlPageConR`.

To remove the `style` attribute altogether you can simply use [jQuery's `removeAttr()` method](http://api.jquery.com/removeattr/):

```
$("table.prtlPageConR").removeAttr("style");
```

Comment: @Joly you're the only one who can answer that question. With the details you've provided this will work fine. If you need help with jQuery please see http://learn.jquery.com and http://try.jquery.com.

Comment: I think it sits in a messy html which is auto generated and hard to show here, I should probably check parents as well, cheers

Answer (score 2):

The problem is mis-understanding of CSS.

`.prtlPageConR table` means 'search for a `table` contained in an element with class `prtlPageConR`'

What you want is `table.prtlPageConR` which means 'search for a table that has the class `prtlPageConR`'

Answer (score 2):

If you just set the style to an empty string, it will reset that individual style.
There were also some issues with your selector as other answers have explained.

```
$("table.prtlPageConR").css({"width":""});
```